# My C++ code in Visual Studio Code is showing an error AccessDenied

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just wrote a code of C++ in Visual Studio Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a=4, b=5;
    cout<<"Operators in C++"<<endl;
    cout<<"Following are the types of operators in C++"<<endl;
    // Arithmetic operators
    cout<<"The value of a + b is "<<(a+b)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of a - b is "<<(a-b)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of a * b is "<<(a*b)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of a / b is "<<(a/b)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of a % b is "<<(a%b)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of a++ is "<<(a++)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of a-- is "<<(a--)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of ++a is "<<(++a)<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of --a is "<<(--a)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it is giving me the following error:

```
Program failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:84
+ ... l\Desktop\C\" ; if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main  } ; if ($?) { .\main }
+                                                                  ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:84
+ ... l\Desktop\C\" ; if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
+                                                                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions to write that file. Maybe your antivirus is the problem. Maybe you used the "Run as administrator"  one time and messed up your permissions.

Comment: ***Please tell me what to do*** Use your OS file explorer to try to discover the reason you don't have permission to run your application.

Comment: The code works till the (a--) operator. But after typing the next line, it gives the error. Therefore, it cannot be an error due to permission @drescherjm

Comment: That is quite odd. I would not expect this OS error to be at all related to the code. With that said your antivirus could be the problem. A slight change in the code could make the AV issue a false positive detection for a virus.

Comment: Thank you so much. The code worked after disabling the antivirus :)